# How to use GNU parallel to run a list of commands where 4 commands run simultaneously

Tags: linux, debian, gnu, gnu-parallel

I have list of shell commands that I'd like to call. Up to four processes shall run at the same time.

As soon as the process count drops below 4, the next command is sent to the shell until all command have finished.

I already got a "partly" working solution from stackoverflow fellows that however rely on wait -n which is not available on my debian wheezy installation.

[Link to other stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27489762/call-shell-commands-from-a-list-of-commands-until-all-commands-have-been-finishe)

One guy mentioned GNU Parallel. Can this be achieved? Any guidance is really appreciated!

```
nohup scrapy crawl urlMonitor -a slice=0 &
nohup scrapy crawl urlMonitor -a slice=1 &
nohup scrapy crawl urlMonitor -a slice=2 &
nohup scrapy crawl urlMonitor -a slice=3 &
nohup scrapy crawl urlMonitor -a slice=4 &
nohup scrapy crawl urlMonitor -a slice=5 &
nohup scrapy crawl urlMonitor -a slice=6 &
nohup scrapy crawl urlMonitor -a slice=7 &
nohup scrapy crawl urlMonitor -a slice=8 &
nohup scrapy crawl urlMonitor -a slice=9 &
nohup scrapy crawl urlMonitor -a slice=10 &
nohup scrapy crawl urlMonitor -a slice=11 &
nohup scrapy crawl urlMonitor -a slice=12 &
nohup scrapy crawl urlMonitor -a slice=13 &
nohup scrapy crawl urlMonitor -a slice=14 &
nohup scrapy crawl urlMonitor -a slice=15 &
nohup scrapy crawl urlMonitor -a slice=16 &
nohup scrapy crawl urlMonitor -a slice=17 &
nohup scrapy crawl urlMonitor -a slice=18 &
nohup scrapy crawl urlMonitor -a slice=19 &
nohup scrapy crawl urlMonitor -a slice=20 &
nohup scrapy crawl urlMonitor -a slice=21 &
nohup scrapy crawl urlMonitor -a slice=22 &
nohup scrapy crawl urlMonitor -a slice=23 &
nohup scrapy crawl urlMonitor -a slice=24 &
nohup scrapy crawl urlMonitor -a slice=25 &
nohup scrapy crawl urlMonitor -a slice=26 &
nohup scrapy crawl urlMonitor -a slice=27 &
nohup scrapy crawl urlMonitor -a slice=28 &
nohup scrapy crawl urlMonitor -a slice=29 &
nohup scrapy crawl urlMonitor -a slice=30 &
nohup scrapy crawl urlMonitor -a slice=31 &
nohup scrapy crawl urlMonitor -a slice=32 &
nohup scrapy crawl urlMonitor -a slice=33 &
nohup scrapy crawl urlMonitor -a slice=34 &
nohup scrapy crawl urlMonitor -a slice=35 &
nohup scrapy crawl urlMonitor -a slice=36 &
nohup scrapy crawl urlMonitor -a slice=37 &
nohup scrapy crawl urlMonitor -a slice=38 &
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have GNU Parallel you can do this:

```
parallel -j4 scrapy crawl urlMonitor -a slice={} ::: {1..38}
```

GNU Parallel is a general parallelizer and makes is easy to run jobs in parallel on the same machine or on multiple machines you have ssh access to.

If you have 32 different jobs you want to run on 4 CPUs, a straight forward way to parallelize is to run 8 jobs on each CPU:

[image: Simple scheduling]

GNU Parallel instead spawns a new process when one finishes - keeping the CPUs active and thus saving time:

[image: GNU Parallel scheduling]

**Installation**

If GNU Parallel is not packaged for your distribution, you can do a personal installation, which does not require root access. It can be done in 10 seconds by doing this:

```
(wget -O - pi.dk/3 || curl pi.dk/3/ || fetch -o - http://pi.dk/3) | bash
```

For other installation options see http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/tree/README

**Learn more**

See more examples: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html

Watch the intro videos: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1

Walk through the tutorial: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html

Sign up for the email list to get support: https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/parallel

Comment: thanks Ole. When I run your command, scrapy processes are not started. Instead the command for the parallel app looks like this in top: /usr/bin/perl -w /usr/bin/parallel -j4 scrapy crawl URLMonitor -a slice={} ::: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38

Comment: this did the trick: needed to add the --gnu option for the command to work. what's the difference between tollef and gnu?

Comment: --tollef is retired. It used to make GNU Parallel compatible with Tollef's parallel from moreutils, but it caused more problems than it solved (which is exactly what you experienced).

Comment: japp.-. especially if this is the default option. should be the other way round maybe if tollref is for compatibility.